One to One problema al crear la relacion
Por mas que pregunto a chatgpt no consigo que funcione.
al hacer un find en persona me da un identificador no valido debido a la relacion.
el problema esta en la relacion one to one con Exitus
Caused by: Error : 904, Position : 1717, SQL = select person0_.ID as ID1_27_0_, person0_.ACTION as ACTION2_27_0_, person0_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION20_27_0_, person0_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_27_0_, person0_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_27_0_, person0_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_27_0_, person0_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_27_0_, person0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE7_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_PLACE as BIRTH_PLACE8_27_0_, person0_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH9_27_0_, person0_.DOCUMENT_IDENTIFICATION as DOCUMENT_IDENTIFI10_27_0_, person0_.DOCUMENT_ID as DOCUMENT_ID21_27_0_, person0_.EXPIRATION_DATE_IDENTIFICATION as EXPIRATION_DATE_I11_27_0_, person0_.GENDER as GENDER12_27_0_, person0_.MARITAL_STATUS as MARITAL_STATUS13_27_0_, person0_.NAME as NAME14_27_0_, person0_.OBSERVATIONS as OBSERVATIONS15_27_0_, person0_.SEX as SEX16_27_0_, person0_.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER as SOCIAL_SECURITY_N17_27_0_, person0_.SURNAME1 as SURNAME18_27_0_, person0_.SURNAME2 as SURNAME19_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID as BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID22_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_ISLAND as BIRTH_ISLAND23_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_LOCALITY as BIRTH_LOCALITY24_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_MUNICIPALITY as BIRTH_MUNICIPALIT25_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_PROVINCE as BIRTH_PROVINCE26_27_0_, documentty1_.ID as ID1_6_1_, documentty1_.ACTION as ACTION2_6_1_, documentty1_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION10_6_1_, documentty1_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_6_1_, documentty1_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_6_1_, documentty1_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_6_1_, documentty1_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_6_1_, documentty1_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIVE7_6_1_, documentty1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_6_1_, documentty1_.DOCUMENT_NAME as DOCUMENT_NAME9_6_1_, exitus2_.ID as ID1_7_2_, exitus2_.ACTION as ACTION2_7_2_, exitus2_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION11_7_2_, exitus2_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_7_2_, exitus2_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_7_2_, exitus2_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_7_2_, exitus2_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_7_2_, exitus2_.DATE_OF_DEATH as DATE_OF_DEATH7_7_2_, exitus2_.FORM_DATE as FORM_DATE8_7_2_, exitus2_.ORIGEN as ORIGEN9_7_2_, exitus2_.person as person12_7_2_, exitus2_.STATE as STATE10_7_2_ from RUP_PERSON person0_ inner join RUP_DOCUMENT_TYPE documentty1_ on person0_.DOCUMENT_ID=documentty1_.ID left outer join RUP_EXITUS exitus2_ on person0_.ID=exitus2_.person where person0_.ID=:1 , Original SQL = select person0_.ID as ID1_27_0_, person0_.ACTION as ACTION2_27_0_, person0_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION20_27_0_, person0_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_27_0_, person0_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_27_0_, person0_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_27_0_, person0_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_27_0_, person0_.ACTIVE as ACTIVE7_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_PLACE as BIRTH_PLACE8_27_0_, person0_.DATE_OF_BIRTH as DATE_OF_BIRTH9_27_0_, person0_.DOCUMENT_IDENTIFICATION as DOCUMENT_IDENTIFI10_27_0_, person0_.DOCUMENT_ID as DOCUMENT_ID21_27_0_, person0_.EXPIRATION_DATE_IDENTIFICATION as EXPIRATION_DATE_I11_27_0_, person0_.GENDER as GENDER12_27_0_, person0_.MARITAL_STATUS as MARITAL_STATUS13_27_0_, person0_.NAME as NAME14_27_0_, person0_.OBSERVATIONS as OBSERVATIONS15_27_0_, person0_.SEX as SEX16_27_0_, person0_.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER as SOCIAL_SECURITY_N17_27_0_, person0_.SURNAME1 as SURNAME18_27_0_, person0_.SURNAME2 as SURNAME19_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID as BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID22_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_ISLAND as BIRTH_ISLAND23_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_LOCALITY as BIRTH_LOCALITY24_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_MUNICIPALITY as BIRTH_MUNICIPALIT25_27_0_, person0_.BIRTH_PROVINCE as BIRTH_PROVINCE26_27_0_, documentty1_.ID as ID1_6_1_, documentty1_.ACTION as ACTION2_6_1_, documentty1_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION10_6_1_, documentty1_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_6_1_, documentty1_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_6_1_, documentty1_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_6_1_, documentty1_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_6_1_, documentty1_.IS_ACTIVE as IS_ACTIVE7_6_1_, documentty1_.DESCRIPTION as DESCRIPTION8_6_1_, documentty1_.DOCUMENT_NAME as DOCUMENT_NAME9_6_1_, exitus2_.ID as ID1_7_2_, exitus2_.ACTION as ACTION2_7_2_, exitus2_.APPLICATION as APPLICATION11_7_2_, exitus2_.CREATION_DATE as CREATION_DATE3_7_2_, exitus2_.CREATION_USER as CREATION_USER4_7_2_, exitus2_.MODIFICATION_DATE as MODIFICATION_DATE5_7_2_, exitus2_.MODIFICATION_USER as MODIFICATION_USER6_7_2_, exitus2_.DATE_OF_DEATH as DATE_OF_DEATH7_7_2_, exitus2_.FORM_DATE as FORM_DATE8_7_2_, exitus2_.ORIGEN as ORIGEN9_7_2_, exitus2_.person as person12_7_2_, exitus2_.STATE as STATE10_7_2_ from RUP_PERSON person0_ inner join RUP_DOCUMENT_TYPE documentty1_ on person0_.DOCUMENT_ID=documentty1_.ID left outer join RUP_EXITUS exitus2_ on person0_.ID=exitus2_.person where person0_.ID=?, Error Message = ORA-00904: "EXITUS2_"."ACTION": identificador no v�lido

estas son las clases person tiene mas cosas pero por abrevair solo pondre lo del common
public class Person extends CommonPerson {}

public class CommonPerson extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * Name of person
     */
    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 50, nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotNull
    private String name;

    /**
     * First surname of the person
     */
    @Column(name = "SURNAME1", length = 60, nullable = false)
    @Size(max = 60)
    @NotNull
    private String surname1;

    /**
     * Second surname of the person
     */
    @Column(name = "SURNAME2", length = 60)
    @Size(max = 60)
    private String surname2;

    /**
     * Date of birth of the person
     */
    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_BIRTH", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;

    /**
     * Sex, DD -> SEX
     */
    @Column(name = "SEX", length = 1)
    @Size(max = 1)
    private String sex;

    /**
     * If the person is active
     */
    @Column(name = "ACTIVE")
    private boolean active;

    /**
     * Marital status, DD -> MARITAL_STATUS
     */
    @Column(name = "MARITAL_STATUS", length = 80)
    @Size(max = 80)
    private String maritalStatus;

    /**
     * In disuse, replaced by table RUP_OBSERVATION
     */
    @Column(name = "OBSERVATIONS", length = 4000)
    @Size(max = 4000)
    private String observations;

    /**
     * Social security number
     */
    @Column(name = "SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER", length = 13)
    @Size(max = 13)
    private String socialSecurityNumber;

    /**
     * Field for specifying the place of birth in case of foreign nationals
     */
    @Column(name = "BIRTH_PLACE", length = 500)
    @Size(max = 500)
    private String birthPlace;

    /**
     * Identification document of the person
     */
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = DocumentType.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DOCUMENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private DocumentType documentType;

    /**
     * FK, type of identification document of the person
     */
    @Column(name = "DOCUMENT_IDENTIFICATION", length = 60, unique = true)
    @NotNull
    private String documentIdentification;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "person")
    private Exitus exitus;

    /**
     * Date of DNI´s expiration of the person
     */
    @Column(name = "EXPIRATION_DATE_IDENTIFICATION")
    private LocalDate expirationDateIdentification;

    @Column(name = "GENDER")
    @Min(value = 1, message = "Gender ID must be at least 1")
    @Max(value = 3, message = "Gender ID must be at most 3")
    private Long gender;
}

esta es la otra clase con la que hacer relacion 1 a 1
public class Exitus extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "exitusSeq")
    @Column(name = "ID", nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "STATE", nullable = false)
    private long state;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
    private Person person;

    @Column(name = "DATE_OF_DEATH", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate dateOfDeath;

    @Column(name = "FORM_DATE", updatable = false)
    private LocalDate formDate;

    @Column(name = "ORIGEN")
    private long origin;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "exitus")
    private List<HistoricalExitus> listHistotical;
}

el dll de exitus
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table RUP_EXITUS
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER, 
    "STATE" NUMBER, 
    "PERSON" NUMBER, 
    "DATE_OF_DEATH" DATE, 
    "FORM_DATE" DATE, 
    "ORIGEN" NUMBER, 
    "MODIFICATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "CREATION_USER" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "CREATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "MODIFICATION_USER" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "APPLICATION" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS"."MODIFICATION_DATE" IS 'Audit modification date (Auto)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS"."CREATION_USER" IS 'Audit user creation (AUTO)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS"."CREATION_DATE" IS 'Audit creation date (AUTO)';
   COMMENT ON COLUMN "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS"."MODIFICATION_USER" IS 'Audit modification user (Auto)';
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Index RUP_EXISTUS_PK
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "RUPER"."RUP_EXISTUS_PK" ON "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" ;
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Constraints for Table RUP_EXITUS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("ID" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_EXITUS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX (CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "RUPER"."RUP_EXISTUS_PK" ON "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ("ID") 
  PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "USERS" )  ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("DATE_OF_DEATH" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("APPLICATION" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("STATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("CREATION_USER" NOT NULL ENABLE);
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" MODIFY ("CREATION_DATE" NOT NULL ENABLE);
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Ref Constraints for Table RUP_EXITUS
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_EXITUS_PERSON_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("PERSON")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_EXITUS_APLICATION_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("APPLICATION")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_APPLICATION" ("CODE") ENABLE;

y el de persona
--------------------------------------------------------
--  DDL for Table RUP_PERSON
--------------------------------------------------------

  CREATE TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" 
   (    "ID" NUMBER(20,0), 
    "NAME" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "SURNAME1" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
    "SURNAME2" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR), 
    "DATE_OF_BIRTH" DATE, 
    "SEX" VARCHAR2(1 CHAR), 
    "CONTACT_LANGUAGE" VARCHAR2(5 CHAR), 
    "MODIFICATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "CREATION_USER" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) DEFAULT user, 
    "SYSTEM_DEACTIVATION_DATE" DATE, 
    "BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID" NUMBER, 
    "BIRTH_PROVINCE" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "BIRTH_ISLAND" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "BIRTH_MUNICIPALITY" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER1" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "PHONE_NUMBER2" VARCHAR2(15 CHAR), 
    "MAIL" VARCHAR2(200 CHAR), 
    "ACTIVE" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "MARITAL_STATUS" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "OBSERVATIONS" VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE), 
    "SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(13 CHAR), 
    "BIRTH_PLACE" VARCHAR2(500 CHAR), 
    "TSU_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20 CHAR), 
    "TSA_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE), 
    "DEACTIVATION_REASON" NUMBER(3,0), 
    "UNDOCUMENTED" NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0, 
    "DOCUMENT_ID" NUMBER, 
    "DOCUMENT_IDENTIFICATION" VARCHAR2(60 BYTE), 
    "CREATION_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE, 
    "MODIFICATION_USER" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    "ACTION" VARCHAR2(6 BYTE) DEFAULT 'CREATE', 
    "APPLICATION" VARCHAR2(10 BYTE) DEFAULT NULL, 
    "DATE_OF_DEATH" DATE, 
    "EXITUS" NUMBER(1,0), 
    "EXPIRATION_DATE_IDENTIFICATION" DATE, 
    "GENDER" NUMBER, 
    "BIRTH_LOCALITY" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
--------------------------------------------------------
--  Ref Constraints for Table RUP_PERSON
--------------------------------------------------------

  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_APPLICATION_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("APPLICATION")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_APPLICATION" ("CODE") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_BIRTH_PROVINCE_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("BIRTH_PROVINCE")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_PROVINCE" ("CODE") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_BIRTH_MUNICIPALITY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("BIRTH_MUNICIPALITY")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_MUNICIPALITY" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_BIRTH_COUNTRY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("BIRTH_COUNTRY_ID")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_COUNTRY" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_DOCUMENT_TYPE_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("DOCUMENT_ID")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_DOCUMENT_TYPE" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_LOCALITY_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("BIRTH_LOCALITY")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_LOCALITY" ("ID") ENABLE;
  ALTER TABLE "RUPER"."RUP_PERSON" ADD CONSTRAINT "RUP_PERSON_EXITUS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("EXITUS")
      REFERENCES "RUPER"."RUP_EXITUS" ("ID") ENABLE;


Pues, primero que nada siempre hay que dirigirse al error.
Dentro del error que mandas, primero mandaste es el Caused by: Error : 904, Position : 1717, el cual indica donde ha ocurrido el error, pero no es el error como tal. El error está al final de ese segmento:
Error Message = ORA-00904: "EXITUS2_"."ACTION": identificador no v�lido

Si tomamos el error y su código, nos dirigimos a Google y buscamos: ORA-00904. Obtenemos lo siguiente en el primer link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/error-help/db/ora-00904/?r=23ai

Si no entendemos inglés, pues, preguntemosle a ChatGPT que nos quiere decir:

Causa: El identificador o nombre de columna ingresado no es válido.
Acción Asegúrese de lo siguiente:
1.- Ingrese un identificador o nombre de columna válido y verifique que no haya errores tipográficos en el identificador o nombre de columna. Un identificador válido debe comenzar con una letra, tener un máximo de 128 caracteres y consistir solo en caracteres alfanuméricos y los caracteres especiales $, _, y #. Si contiene otros caracteres, debe estar entre comillas dobles. 
2.- No debe ser una palabra reservada a menos que esté entre comillas dobles. 
3.- Si se usaron comillas dobles y mayúsculas y minúsculas mezcladas para un nombre de columna al crear la tabla, entonces las referencias a esa columna deben usar las mismas mayúsculas y comillas.

Entonces, que hay que hacer ahora ???
Revisar la estructura de la tabla RUP_EXITUS y confirmar que ACTION es el nombre correcto de la columna.
AL parecer te has equivocado, y has buscado ACTION dentro de RUP_EXITUS, cuando ACTION está dentro de RUP_PERSON.
De ser correcto, y tu ver todo bien, comparte una imagen de la tabla y sus columnas por favor. Edita la publicación y agregala alla.

MUCHAS gracias estaba obcecado en que era problema de la relacion y no vi que me faltaba un campo en la tabla que si estaba en la entidad

No pasa nada, siempre hay que revisar bien el error ;)
